# I need to compare two sets and alert on any matched elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, compare

Brand new to python.

First
I want to pull in a list of IP addresses from the body of a webpage using requests.  I have that list and have used -Splitlines- to format my list and remove anything other than IP addresses.  I am adding this list to a set.

Second
I want to pull in a list of IP address from a CSV file.  I have the list and have also formated using -Splitlines- and added to a set. However, if I run a len on the set, I am missing around 1,000 lines (out of 18,000).

Additionally, I've tried several different ways to compare the sets, but I don't see to be getting any Red Flags that an element exist in both sets.  This could be due to missing lines.

4 hours worth of Googling - finally decided to ask for help

````
r = requests.get(url) 

black = set() 
for line in r.text.splitlines(): 
    bip = line.split(' ')[0]  
    black.add(bip) 
# print(black) # Print for testing


file = "file_wip.csv"

white = set()
with open(file, 'r') as filehandle:
    for line in filehandle:
      wip = line.split(',')[0] 
      white.add(wip)
# print(white) # Print for testing

# black.intersection(white) <-- my attempts to compare
# set(black) == set(white)```


1. len on the sets do not provide an accurate line count
2. comparing the sets is blank
````

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're looking for, [here are the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) in python 3 for set operations. You could try `black & white` (which it looks like you've done), `black - white` for the difference, `black ^ white` for symmetric difference, `black < white`, `black>=white` for subsetting. Are you trying to find elements that _are_ in both, are you trying to find elements that are _only_ in one or the other? Some sample input and output might help

Comment: I apologize for the confusions.  I am trying to find the elements (IP Addresses) that are in both.
`set from url
93.43.2.3
83.23.2.2
98.21.2.4

set from csv
54.54.3.2
90.90.32.3
98.21.2.4
`
I'd like to get an alert on the 98.21.2.4 address being in both sets

Comment: Based on what you included, `url & csv` and `url.intersection(csv)` return `{'98.21.2.4'}`, and `any(i in url for i in csv)` returns `True`. Have you checked for formatting differences? Leading or trailing whitespace/line breaks are a common culprit.

Comment: And, regarding the fact that your list is "missing" elements, are there any duplicates in the original? That would account for a length difference.

Comment: Thanks G. Anderson!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic seems to be correct

```
black = set(['93.43.2.3', '83.23.2.2' ,'98.21.2.4'])
white = set(['54.54.3.2' ,'90.90.32.3' ,'98.21.2.4'])

print(black.intersection(white))
```

Output

```
{'98.21.2.4'}
```

Have you checked the `print(black)` and `print(white)` output for any discrepancies?

If your data has duplicate values they will be removed. It might be the reason for length mismatch